# Can you enter the UK via Eurostar on an EU passport with only one month of validity?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, eu-citizens, eurostar

I'm like two hours away and just realised my passport will expire in September.

Comment: How about your identity card?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [the passport only needs to be valid throughout your stay](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/before-you-leave-for-the-uk). If you need to stay longer, you could also renew your passport through your country's consulate. I don't have a reference at hand but I think EU countries cannot impose any requirement to EU citizens beyond having a valid passport or national ID card (i.e. no three or six months of validity).

Comment: The relevant reference is Article 4 through 6 of [Directive 2004/38](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616).